# How to change the code so it works not only for the static values "general" and "plus"?

Tags: php, laravel

A registration in a conference has 1 or more participants associated and each participant associated with the registration is associated with a registration type.

I have a query to get the info(name and price) about each registration type associated with a participant in a specific registration, the result of the query is:

```
Registration {#258 ▼
  ...
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#262 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#269 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▶]
          ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#274 ▶}
          ]
          ... // then RegistrationType has attributes: name, price, etc
        }
        1 => Participant {#271 ▼
          #fillable: array:4 [▶]
          ...
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#274 ▼
              ... // then RegistrationType has attributes: name, price, etc
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 ...
}
```

Now I want to show a summary of the registration like:

```
Registration type        Quantity            Price           Subtotal
general                1                  0.00             0.00
plus                   2                  2.00             4.00
```

I have the code below to get this summary but its working with the static registration type names (general" and plus). But a registration type can have any name, the user that creates a conference can create registration tyes with any name. Do you know how to achieve this same summary but with any registration type name instead of just the static values "general" and "plus"?

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li>
        <span>Registration Type</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span>Price</span>
        <span>Subtotal</span>
    </li>

    <?php
    $general_type_count = 0;
    $plus_type_count = 0;
    foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
        if($p->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
            $general_type_count ++;
        if($p->registration_type['name'] === 'plus')
            $plus_type_count ++;
    }
    $plus = 0; $general = 0;
    ?>
    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
        <li>
            <span> {{$participant->registration_type['name']}} </span>
            <span>
                @if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
                    {{$general_type_count}}
                @endif
                @if($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'plus')
                    {{$plus_type_count}}
                @endif
             </span>
            <?php
            if ($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'general')
                $general++;
            if ($participant->registration_type['name'] === 'plus')
                $plus++;
            ?>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price']}} </span>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price'] * $general_type_count}} </span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The controller that returns the "registrationTypeDetails":

```
class PController extends Controller
{
    public function showSummary($id = "", $slug = "", $regID)
    {
      $registrationDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,ticket_type_id,registration_id')->find($registrationID);
        return view('conferences.showSummary', compact(registrationTypeDetails'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array instead of variables:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li>
        <span>Registration Type</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span>Price</span>
        <span>Subtotal</span>
    </li>

    <?php
    $type_counts = [];
    foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
        if (!isset($type_counts[$p->registration_type['name']])) {
            $type_counts[$p->registration_type['name']] = 0;
        }
        $type_counts[$p->registration_type['name']]++;
    }
    ?>
    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
        <li>
            <span> {{$participant->registration_type['name']}} </span>
            <span>
                {{$type_counts[$participant->registration_type['name']]}}
             </span>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price']}} </span>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price'] * $type_counts[$participant->registration_type['name']]}} </span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I removed `$general` and `plus`, which were unused. You can do the same for those if you need them.

It would also be a good idea to use a variable for `$type_counts[$participant->registration_type['name']]`, which is used very often. That would avoid a lot of repetition:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li>
        <span>Registration Type</span>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <span>Price</span>
        <span>Subtotal</span>
    </li>

    <?php
    $type_counts = [];
    foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
        $name = $p->registration_type['name'];
        if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
            $type_counts[$name] = 0;
        }
        $type_counts[$name]++;
    }
    ?>
    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
        @php ($name = $participant->registration_type['name'])
        <li>
            <span> {{$name]}} </span>
            <span>
                {{$type_counts[$name]}}
             </span>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price']}} </span>
            <span class="font-size-sm">{{$participant->registration_type['price'] * $type_counts[$name]}} </span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, with second approach it appears "Undefined index: test" in "$type_counts[$name]++;". Also, do you know how to have below the @endforeach a list item that shows the correct total (sum of the subtotals)? Like  "<li>

                <span>TOTAL</span>

                <span>show total here</span>
            </li>"?

Comment: "test" is the name of a registration type.

Comment: @johnW For the sum, you can initially set a variable to 0. Then, for each iteration, add the count to that variable. When the loop finishes, that variable will be the sum.

Comment: @johnW The second code should have the same results. Did you use the edited version? I don’t use Larvel very often, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks, yes with the edited version it appears that error and it seems that is in this line "$type_counts[$name]++;".

Comment: Even if the code stay just only like this: "  <?php  $type_counts = [];
  foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
      $name = $p->registration_type['name'];if (!isset($name)) {$type_counts[$name] = 0;    }$type_counts[$name]++;
     }
                                    ?>
                                    @foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant)
                                      
                                    @endforeach" the error appears so the error should be in inside the <?php ?>.

Comment: Event if the code stays just with only " <?php $type_counts = [];
                                    foreach($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p){
                                        $name = $p->registration_type['name'];
                                        if (!isset($name)) {
                                            $type_counts[$name] = 0;
                                        }
                                        $type_counts[$name]++;
                                    }
                                    ?>" that error appears.

Comment: Thanks, now it appears "Use of undefined constant registration_type - assumed 'registration_type'". Do you know why? But now the error is in the "                                            <span class="font-size-sm">{{ number_format($participant->registration_type['price'], 2)}}
".

Comment: @johnW You should probably ask a new question for that. That error should not be caused by that line, so I think it needs more context.

Comment: Thanks, the total is not working properly, it should be 2 but it is appearing 1. I set the total in the <?php ... ?> like "<?php $total = 0; ... ?>". Then inside the foreach I have "                                        @php ($total +=$participant->registration_type->price)
". And then after the "@endforeach" I have "{{ number_format($total, 2)}}". Do you know where is the issue?